# Auto number fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, auto-increment

I have a field in my SQL Server 2008 table that is auto number incremental of 1 and has over 100,000 records in it.

We are migrating servers at the moment so I'm looking at doing a little spring cleaning and will be deleting all the records from this table.

I still want the auto number incremental of 1 facility but I would like the first record to start at 102001, is this possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, simply set the start value of [IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) to be your chosen number. Syntax: `IDENTITY (seed,increment)`

```
CREATE TABLE Customers
(
  CustomerID int IDENTITY(102001, 1),
  Name nvarchar(MAX)
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I have used this TSQL command in the past to re-seed an auto number column in a table

```
 DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.TABLE', RESEED, 102001)
```